# Background color of a Gtk.TextView - can't see selection

Tags: pygtk, pygobject

I successfully changed the background color of a Gtk.TextView (GTK3) with method override_background_color:

```
color.parse(self.settings.get_string("bgcolor"))
self.ui.NoteView.override_background_color(Gtk.StateType.NORMAL,color)
```

I also override the foreground color.
Unfortunatelly in that case making a selection in the text is invisible.
How can I modify the background and foreground color of a TextView without loosing the visible text selecting?

Answer (score 0):

It's best to format the text in a GtkTextView by using `GtkTextTags`. You can apply any sort of text formatting(background & foreground colors, font, size, weight, etc..) to any portion of the text.

Click [here](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/textview.html#tags) for an example.
Hope that helps!

By the way, what you're doing is changing the style of your `TextView`. In `Gtk` it's best to stay away from doing this, especially if you aren't in a controlled environment or plan on releasing your software for others to use, because gtk's philosophy is to leave the styling and theming up to the end user for their own personal touches/needs. 
This is why you are getting some unwanted results by overriding style colors.
In terms of a `GtkTextView` it *does* however offer simple formatting of the text(even support for adding images/widgets) via use of `GtkTextTags` as the link shows above.

Comment: -Thanks I understand, but I want that the user change the bg and fg colors of a textview through a preferences window (just for customizing). This textview holds only plain text without formatting. override would be ok if I could set it for the selected text but this self.ui.NoteView.override_background_color(Gtk.StateType.SELECTED,scolor) does not work. I guess I need to apply tags on the text when a selection change. Am I right?

Comment: Applying tags when selection changes is probably the most theme-safe way to go about this. But if you're really bent on overriding the theme, look into `widget.modify_base` too. That might affect the selection color of the `GtkTextView` but I'm not certain of it.